# Is there a way to obfuscate TailwindCSS classnames using PostCSS for React project in Vitejs?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, vite

Currently building a React project with ViteJs, which uses TailwindCSS & PostCSS.

I would like the tailwind classnames to be obfuscated in the production build. Like `object-cover` to `a2`. Also, I am not aiming for minification.

I have tried looking for solutions but no luck.

Here is the postcss config:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://medium.com/geekculture/obfuscate-tailwind-classes-in-a-laravel-project-71694b9d8ac1

Answer (score 2):

with the following code I managed to replace the classnames `only in the css file`, i can't find a way to replace it in the javascript as well, hope to find some solution soon.

`vite.config.js`

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import {createHtmlPlugin} from "vite-plugin-html";
import postcssRename from "postcss-rename";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";
export default async ({mode}) => {
 
    return defineConfig({

        plugins: [
            react(),
            createHtmlPlugin({
                minify: true,
            }),
        ],
        css: {
            postcss: {
                plugins: [
                    tailwindcss(('./tailwind.config.cjs')),
                    postcssRename({
                        strategy:  (input)=>{
                            return random(6)
                        },
                        outputMapCallback: function (map) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(map));

                        }
                    })
                ]
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: 9000
        }
    });
};

function random(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve? In the console it shows everything ok, but I don't know how to generate this CSS, I'm using Laravel 10 + vite + Tailwindcss

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [postcss-obfuscator](https://replit.com/@n4j1Br4ch1D/postcss-obfuscator-react-vite-tailwindcss) plugins, its work pretty well :

1- install postcss-obfuscator:

```
# npm
npm install postcss-obfuscator --save-dev
# yarn

yarn add postcss-obfuscator --dev
```

2- install tailwindcss and configure it:

```
# Using NPM
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

3- create src/input.css and import tailwindcss:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4- create postcss.config.cjs this minimum config I used in demo

```
//postcss.config.cjs 

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development" //development //obfuscation //production
const isObfscMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'obfuscation'; 

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-obfuscator')({
    /* options */
      enable: isObfscMode, // Force Run on Dev Env or when srcPath equals desPath.
      srcPath: "src", // Source of your files.
      desPath: "out", // Destination for obfuscated html/js/.. files.
      extensions: ['.jsx'],
      formatJson: true, // Format obfuscation data JSON file.
    })
  ]
}
```

5- add this npm script's to package.json

```
"tailwindcss": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css",
"postcss": "postcss src/**/*.css  --dir out/css",
"obfuscate": "npm run tailwindcss && npm run postcss"
```

6- Install postcss-cli:

```
npm i -D postcss postcss-cli
```

7- now to obfuscate, set the env mode to obfuscation , and in your console run :

```
 npm run obfuscate
```

Answer (score 0):

If Tailwind isn't a hard requirement or you're open to switch, which could possibly be a drop-in replacement depending on you usage & config [UnoCSS](https://github.com/unocss/unocss) works really great and provides the [transformer-compile-class](https://github.com/unocss/unocss/tree/main/packages/transformer-compile-class/)

With this plugin installed you can prefix a class string with `:uno:` (can be changed) and have

```html
<div class=":uno: text-center sm:text-left">
  <div class=":uno: text-sm font-bold hover:text-red"/>
</div>
```

be compiled to

```
<div class="uno-qlmcrp">
  <div class="uno-0qw2gr"/>
</div>
.uno-qlmcrp {
  text-align: center;
}
.uno-0qw2gr {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.uno-0qw2gr:hover {
  --un-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(248, 113, 113, var(--un-text-opacity));
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .uno-qlmcrp {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Examples taken from the plugin readme

Answer (score 0):

## August 2023

I recommend using the [`postcss-rename`](https://github.com/google/postcss-rename) plugin.

Configure your `postcss.config.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    'postcss-rename': {
      strategy: 'minimal',
      by: 'whole',
      ids: true,
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

This setup will effectively rename all CSS classes and HTML IDs.

| However, in some cases, solely relying on this plugin might not be enough. You might also need to process your HTML output to align with the new names.