# React/Tailwindcss modules name obfuscation breaks postcss nesting

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, css-modules

So after extensive research I am here, I have a difficult to search problem which I'm hoping can be solved.

I've booted up a new project with Vite/ReactJS/Tailwindcss and I'm trying to use postcss to create nested CSS rules, they seem to be partially working but when using the ampersand (as in SCSS) things get a bit weird.

I have a bog standard Button React component with the following `Button.module.css`:

```css
.Button {
    @apply bg-primary;

    &--disabled {
        @apply opacity-50;
    }
}
```

Styles are applied like so:

```js
import styles from './Button.module.css';

const Button = ({ label, disabled }) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" className={[
            styles.Button,
            disabled ? 'Button--disabled' : ''
        ]}>
            {label}
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

`postcss.config.cjs`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

However in the browser the button looks like, note the obfuscated classes:

```html
<button type="button" class="Button _Button_1fcg7_1 Button--disabled">Button</button>
```

While the (successfully, I note) compiled CSS looks like:

```css
._Button_1fcg7_1 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(29 161 242 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}
._Button--disabled_1fcg7_1 {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

Because the class name in the HTML compiles to `.Button--disabled` and the CSS selector gets obfuscated to `._Button--disabled_1fcg7_1`, the styles are never applied.  What gives?

---

Some further info as requested, `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^10.1.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

`tailwind.config.cjs`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#1da1f2',
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's funny because different people with similar setups have the opposite problem.

[Is there a way to obfuscate TailwindCSS classnames using PostCSS for React project in Vitejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008195/is-there-a-way-to-obfuscate-tailwindcss-classnames-using-postcss-for-react-proje)

I think that your problem comes from another place.
Can you share your `package.json`, `tailwind.config.js`, `vite.config.js` and `rollup.config.js` (if you have this last file) ?

Maybe you have some settings or packages configured related to obfuscation.

I don't know the vite ecosystem, but there are some packages that generate the behavior you want to avoid:

- vite-plugin-tailwind-ofuscar
- rollup-plugin-postcss

Comment: Thanks for your comment, have just added the `package.json` and `vite.config.ts`.  It's all pretty standard out-of-the-box Vite cli setup though other than storybook which I added

Comment: Okay @Charlie. Sorry, but I honestly don't know how to help you right now, even with the files you gave me. I guess sooner or later someone more knowledgeable will come along and may end up giving you a hand. Or even, hopefully, you can solve your problem yourself. Anyway, keep the files I asked you to put, they may be useful.

Comment: Yeah not using rollup at all.  No worries, glad it's not just something silly I missed!  Full stack dev for 10+ years but fairly new to React and first time actually trying Vite